# Use form post (php) to upload a file to Azure storage, and return the link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, azure

I have read a number of solutions here and elsewhere that show how a upload a file to an Azure Blob storage. I have the php code working below when the file is hard coded (followed the MS tutorial), but not if I try to post the file to the PHP (get error: not a valid path). I want a user to be able to browse to a file in the form and submit (then return the url so that I can use it for other actions). I read on SO that javascript shows a fake path for security, and I assume that is my issue. How, then, do I get the proper path to the PHP file if I cannot post it. I have tried a default post and an ajax attempt. Is there a solution?

My PHP (works when the file is hard coded):

```
 require_once 'WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.php';
 use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
 use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;

 $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=mykey";
 // Create blob REST proxy.
 $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

 //$content = fopen("c:\myfile.txt", "r"); //this works when hard coded like this
 //$blob_name = "myblob.txt";
 //get posts
 //$fpath = $_POST["resFile"];//tried this too - no go
  $fpath = $_FILES["resFile"];
  $fname = "hello.txt";

  $content = fopen($fpath, "r"); //I know this isn't right, but trying
  $blob_name = $fname;

 try {
     //Upload blob
     $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("saskcontainer", $blob_name, $content);
 }
 catch(ServiceException $e){
// Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
// Error codes and messages are here: 
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179439.aspx
$code = $e->getCode();
$error_message = $e->getMessage();
echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
 }
 //and I need to return the url here on success
```

here is the HTML and JS:

```
 <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div data-role='page' id="resFileCont" >

    <input type="file" name="resFile" id="resFile" value="" />
    <!--<input type="text" name="name" />-->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-inline="true"/>
</div></form>
<div id="res"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").on('submit', (function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php", // Url to which the request is send
                type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
                data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
                contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
                processData: false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                success: function (data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
                {
                    alert(data)
                    $("#res").html(data)
                }
            });
        }));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Got it. Simple solutions that tool way too long: `$content = fopen($_FILES["resFile"]["tmp_name"], 'r');`

Comment: You should add your comment as answer and accept it as that worked for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replaced 
`$content = fopen($fpath, "r");` 
with 
`$content = fopen($_FILES["resFile"]["tmp_name"], 'r');`